# bash completion -X for multiple file prefixes and ignoring pattern

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I have this complete function the works with one file prefix.

How can I do it for multiple types?

Files: `foo.12345`  `bar.87654`

Works with only one file:

```
complete -f -X '!foo.*' MyScript
```

Things I've tried that doesn't work:

```
complete -f -X '!+(foo|bar).*' MyScript
complete -f -X '!*+(foo|bar).*' MyScript
complete -f -X '!(foo|bar).*' MyScript
```

Is there also a way to ignore some files in this pattern? For example to match `foo.12345` and `bar.87654` but ignore `bar.ignore.56565`?

Thanks!

Comment: Uhm, you have to be quite specific, in your example you can do `???.?????`, as `?` matches a single character.

Comment: The number of character changes. I'd like to get those specific prefixes. The suffixes may vary. In the 2nd question, I also have a specific string I'd want to ignore. Any answer for either question would be helpful.